# Autoloader issue not returning Class

Tags: php, namespaces, autoloader

**Problem?**

Bootloader (Autoloader) does not seem to be working properly, or I'm missing something. Here is the simplified code.

The code below returns

> Class "Skeleton" does not exist.

On index.php file.

**index.php**

```
<?php

include 'bootloader.php';
use Skeleton\Html\LoginHeader;
$tool = new Skeleton/Html/LoginHeader();
```

**bootloader.php**

```
<?php

function Boot($className) {
        $fileName = '';
        $namespace = '';

        // Sets the include path as the "src" directory
        $includePath = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src';

        if (false !== ($lastNsPos = strripos($className, '\\'))) {
            $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
            $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
            $fileName = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }
        $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
        $fullFileName = $includePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

        if (file_exists($fullFileName)) {
            require $fullFileName;
        } else {
            echo 'Class "'.$className.'" does not exist.';
        }
    }
    spl_autoload_register('Boot'); // Registers the autoloader
```

**src/Skeleton/Html/LoginHeader.php**

```
<?php

namespace Skeleton\Html;

class LoginHeader () {
    echo "<h1>Login Header OK!</h1>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple issues here:

1) This line/section is not right:

```
class LoginHeader () {
```

Should be:

```
class LoginHeader
    {
        public function __construct()
            {
                echo "<h1>Login Header OK!</h1>";
                ...etc
```

2) You are not assigning your class correctly. You have:

```
$tool = new Skeleton/Html/LoginHeader();
```

Should be backslashes:

```
            --------v----v
$tool = new Skeleton\Html\LoginHeader();
```

Once you fix your backslashes, you will get a syntax error on the class page as noted, but your autoloader itself works fine.